# Is it possible to reinitialize the default firebase app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
//first call to initialize app
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}
```

When the user logs out, I need them to disconnect to the realtime database.

```
firebase.app().delete().then( () => {
 if (!firebase.apps.length) 
 {
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
 }
 this.goToSignin();
})
```

However, when I try to sign in again I get an error saying the default app is already deleted

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already deleted (app/app-deleted).
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're supposed to ever re-initialize an app of the same name, even if the previous one is deleted. But I'm not entirely sure, so it might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

In the meantime, I'd recommend generating named app instances, so that you can control their name.

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(config, "myname");
```

You can then pass `app` around and use that instead of `firebase` in most places.